# p7zip_15.09 compiling failed on MAC OS X El Capitan

Tags: macos, clang, 7zip, clang++, llvm-clang

Operation system name: MAC OS X El Capitan 
Operation system version: 10.11.3 (15D21)
Compiler version: Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)
7zip source code version: p7zip_15.09

error message:
ld: internal error: atom not found in symbolIndex(__ZN12NCoderMixer29CBindInfoaSERKS0_) for architecture x86_64

Answer (score 0):

clang cannot support -s flag,
so modify the makefile.machine file,
change "OPTFLAGS=-O -s" to "OPTFLAGS=-O"